# Replace empty cells with 0 - SSAS

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube

I want to replace empty cells within olap cube by 0 in order to show them without having to click on "Show empty cells" button (ssms). I mean even if we don't click on it, empty cells are changed with 0s and shown.
Is there a way to achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this case in the ETL, to either replace the NULL values with 0 OR with NoValue, depending on the context. But if you really want to do it in the Cube, then you can add an MDX script to your calculations, something like:

```
SCOPE ([Measures].[Activity]);
THIS=IIF(ISEMPTY([Measures].[Activity]),0,[Measures].[Activity]);
END SCOPE;
```

More detailed info
[here](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/bidn-blog/6216/how-to-display-0-rsquo-s-instead-of-null-in-your-ssas-cube-amp-mdx-query-results).

Answer (score 1):

If you set a default value of zero won't it make your data dense?